# Excel VBA Using Select Case to delete cells in a Range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of data, and I am programming to remove a names from a range. Here is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectCase()

Dim msg As String
Dim VarCase As Range

Set VarCase = Worksheets("Data").Range("D:D")

Select Case VarCase

    Case VarCase = "Zamora"
    VarCase.Delete

    Case VarCase = "John"
    VarCase.Delete

End Select

End Sub
```

I am getting an error message Run-time error '13' Type mismatch, is this due to trying to use a string ("Zamora/John") with a range?

Comment: 1. You can't equate a full column to a single value, you will need to loop or use find() or some other method to check the value.  2. It should just be `Case  "Zamora"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! You might want to add it so it checks to see if John and Zamora aren't all lower case if that is needed.

```
Sub SelectCase()

Dim msg As String
Dim VarCase As Range

For Each VarCase In ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
  If VarCase.Value2 = "John" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Zamora" Then
  VarCase.ClearContents
  End If
Next VarCase
End Sub
```